# floating text and icon in html table using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I want the display somehow like,
[image].

I tried,

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css">


<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead class="text-center">
    <tr>
      <th>Service</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>--></td>
    <td><span class="float-left"><i class="fas fa-caret-square-down fa-4x"></i></span><span class="text-center">8</span><span class="float-right"><i class="fas fa-caret-square-up fa-4x"></i></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>--></td>
    <td><span class="float-left"><i class="fas fa-caret-square-down fa-4x"></i></span><span class="text-center">12</span><span class="float-right"><i class="fas fa-caret-square-up fa-4x"></i></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>--></td>
    <td><span class="float-left"><i class="fas fa-caret-square-down fa-4x"></i></span><span class="text-center">4</span><span class="float-right"><i class="fas fa-caret-square-up fa-4x"></i></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>--></td>
    <td><span class="float-left"><i class="fas fa-caret-square-down fa-4x"></i></span><span class="text-center">6</span><span class="float-right"><i class="fas fa-caret-square-up fa-4x"></i></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not good practice to add individual classes on child **elements**, we have to control it from the parent element. It can be achieved by using **Flexbox**.

First Remove `float-left`, `text-center` and `float-right` classes from child elements and just add `d-flex`, `justify-content-between` and `align-items-center` on parent **td**. Try this I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
.fas {
  height: 56px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fas:before {
  margin-top: -4px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css">


<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead class="text-center">
    <tr>
      <th>Service</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>--></td>
    <td class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center p-0">
      <i class="fas fa-caret-square-down fa-4x"></i>
      <span>8</span>
      <i class="fas fa-caret-square-up fa-4x"></i>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>--></td>
    <td class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center p-0">
      <i class="fas fa-caret-square-down fa-4x"></i>
      <span>12</span>
      <i class="fas fa-caret-square-up fa-4x"></i>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>--></td>
    <td class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center p-0">
      <i class="fas fa-caret-square-down fa-4x"></i>
      <span>4</span>
      <i class="fas fa-caret-square-up fa-4x"></i>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>--></td>
    <td class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center p-0">
      <i class="fas fa-caret-square-down fa-4x"></i>
      <span>6</span>
      <i class="fas fa-caret-square-up fa-4x"></i>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Your answer satisfies me, but partially. In the image, you can see `<i class="fas fa-caret-square-__"></i>`  is touching the borders. `.fa-4x` was just used to show what I was trying, actually, the icon should automatically adjust itself according to the cell height (100%) and should touch the borders.

Comment: By adding `p-0` you can remove **left** and **right** space, but **top** and **bottom** space of icon it's actually coming in the font-awesome icon. To resolve this issue we have to apply fixed height on the icon. If you good with that I'll update the code according to your requirement.

Comment: I just update the code snippet according to your requirement. Try this I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

Comment: `.fa-4x` was just used to show what I was trying, actually, the icon should automatically adjust itself according to the cell height (100%) and should touch the borders.

Comment: How to adjust it in normal icons? (no `.fa-4x`)

Comment: **font-awesome** icons not working on **height** or **width** they need **font-size** and I believe there is no class for a responsive icon in **font-awesome**. If you want your icons dependent on parent height you have to use your icons as a background image.

Comment: Why there's a line in the cell? jsfiddle.net/rx28jsu4/2

Comment: Remove `p-0` class from **td**.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making parent element `position:relative` and to center the content, you can use `position:absolute;left:50%;transform:translateX(-50%)`

```css
td {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px!important;
  border: 0
}

span.text-center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.table td {
  border: 0px!important
}

tr {
  line-height: 13px;
}

.fas {
  background: black
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css">


<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead class="text-center">
    <tr>
      <th>Service</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>--></td>
    <td><span class="float-left"><i class="fas fa-caret-square-down"></i></span><span class="text-center">8</span><span class="float-right"><i class="fas fa-caret-square-up"></i></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>--></td>
    <td><span class="float-left"><i class="fas fa-caret-square-down"></i></span><span class="text-center">12</span><span class="float-right"><i class="fas fa-caret-square-up"></i></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>--></td>
    <td><span class="float-left"><i class="fas fa-caret-square-down"></i></span><span class="text-center">4</span><span class="float-right"><i class="fas fa-caret-square-up"></i></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>--></td>
    <td><span class="float-left"><i class="fas fa-caret-square-down"></i></span><span class="text-center">6</span><span class="float-right"><i class="fas fa-caret-square-up"></i></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Your answer satisfies me, but partially. In the image, you can see `<i class="fas fa-caret-square-__"></i>`  is touching the borders. `.fa-4x` was just used to show what I was trying, actually, the icon should automatically adjust itself according to the cell height (100%) and should touch the borders.

Comment: you can remove padding and margin @keso

Comment: Icons are not touching the top and bottom borders: https://jsfiddle.net/rx28jsu4/

Comment: As you can see you have used bootstrap class border. That doesn't work. Remove the border from table to get that happen

Comment: check now. Updated the answer

Comment: @keso check now. Updated my answer as per your jsfiddle. You need to reduce `line-height` when you use smaller font

Comment: No, I don't want to change the height of the row! (Icons should be adjusted as par the cell)

Comment: Then you must use media queries and set the font size for different devices.